# jquery modal dialog onclick?

Tags: jquery, dialog, modal-dialog

I want this:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-message

to happend when you click on ClickMe.

how to do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('div.thedialog').dialog({ autoOpen: false })
$('#thelink').click(function(){ $('div.thedialog').dialog('open'); });
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="thedialog" title="Download complete">
    <p>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span>
        Your files have downloaded successfully into the My Downloads folder.
    </p>
    <p>
        Currently using <b>36% of your storage space</b>.
    </p>
</div>
<a href="#" id="thelink">Clickme</a>
```

nothing happends

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of `div.thedialog`, give `div#thedialog`. the `.` is used with class names and `#` is used when you are working with ids.

( Also, if this is the actual code you used, there was a missing bracket :) )

The working code:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.0/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('div#thedialog').dialog({ autoOpen: false })
$('#thelink').click(function(){ $('div#thedialog').dialog('open'); });
})
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="thedialog" title="Download complete">
    <p>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span>
        Your files have downloaded successfully into the My Downloads folder.
    </p>
    <p>
        Currently using <b>36% of your storage space</b>.
    </p>
</div>
<a href="#" id="thelink">Clickme</a>
</body>
```

Comment: +1 just dont forget to include the stylesheet, its looks better :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the [jQuery UI](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog) Dialog, in `$(document).ready(...)` do:

```
$('div.thedialog').dialog({ autoOpen: false })
```

to create the dialog and

```
$('#thelink').click(function(){ $('div.thedialog').dialog('open'); });
```

to open it.

Comment: Doesnt work.. i have this: 
<a href="#" id="thelink">Clickme</a> and then those two lines in document ready, and then a div box called "thedialog" but it wont work

Answer (score 0):

@Azzyh I thing that @Rune means that you have to make a script for it.

You put this into the  tag of your html

```
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

(also you have to have the JQuery-ui script and JQuery script too linked to your page with the  as sawn above (ex 
`<script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`) <- in witch case he load the script of the internet).

Where script.js is the script file ( in the same folder as the html file ).

Now, in the script.js you write

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('div.thedialog').dialog({ autoOpen: false })
   $('#thelink').click(function(){ $('div.thedialog').dialog('open'); });
});
```

PS: Read [this book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/jQuery-Action-Second-Bear-Bibeault/dp/1935182323/) if you like to learn how to do All that cool stuff you see on the internet.