# onClick Modal Dialog

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Similar to: [jquery modal dialog onclick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353037/jquery-modal-dialog-onclick)

However I have a different requirement and cannot apply the solutions provided in that post.

At the moment I am using JQuery <s>within php</s> to parse through an xml file and produce content on a HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "uploads/data.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                error: function() {
                    $('#message').text('Please upload the XML file.');
                },
                success: xmlParser
            });
        });

        function xmlParser(xml){
            $('.tmpli').hide();


            $(xml).find("vendor-one").each(function(){
                $("#vendor-one").append('<li class="sweet">' + $(this).find("name").text() + '</li>');
                $(".sweet").fadeIn();
            });

        }
    </script>
```

I attempted an alert triggered by `onClick` however it's not able to contain images:

```
$(xml).find("vendor-one").each(function(){
    $("#vendor-one").append('<li class="sweet" onClick="alert(\''+$(this).find("name").text()+'\');">' + $(this).find("name").text() + '</li>');
    $(".sweet").fadeIn();
});
```

I then attempted this however it opens a dialog box for every li element on the page and I'm unsure how to edit the text and add an image:

```
$(xml).find("vendor-one").each(function(){
    $("#vendor-one").append('<li class="sweet">' + $(this).find("name").text() + '</li>');
    $(".sweet").fadeIn();
    $('li.sweet').click(function(){ $('li.sweet').dialog(); });
});
```

I need a facility where I am able to click on each individual `li` item created and have a message box appear that contains an image and text. 
I was intending to use this: [Modal Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog) however I'm unsure of how to mend it to my needs.

How do you do this?

Comment: Writing it first in pure jQuery would be so much easier for debugging than directly into php... Your problem is not even related to php, you should strip out the context to find the problem.

Comment: I agree with blex more over can you provide us the information that which dialog are you using ?

Comment: To ease your eyes and ours you can rewrite the `echo "replace \" with '"`. Perhaps do a retest and let us know if you get any javascript errors in your console (F12).

Comment: @AkhileshSharma I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by dialog? The text I wish to be displayed or the dialog box I am trying to display?

Comment: From the second I start doing that, just to prove how easy you miss little things ..., `$(xml).find(\"vendor-one\")` finds `vendor-one` object or `#vendor-one` selector?

Comment: It whether you are using the jquery dialog or some thrid party plugin or simple javascript dialog ?

Comment: @blex I have updated the post and everything is in JQuery.

Comment: @TimVermaelen following the advise above, everything is now in JQuery which removes the various escapes. In relation to your question, it will find the tag in the xml document called "vendor-one".

Comment: @AkhileshSharma I am looking to use this one: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the manual `onclick` inline option, you can use the Javascript way to do it.

```
document.getElementById('ElementID').addEventListener('click', function(event){
   console.log(event);
});
```

Or the JQuery way (which results in the same thing) :

```
$('#ElementID').click(function(event){
   console.log(event);
});
```